# TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'r'

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, python-docx

First of all, I import my libraries:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
import pandas as pd
import jinja2
```

Then, I code this:

```
doc = DocxTemplate('note-6-template.docx') #open my template

context = {

    'cur_year': 2019,
    'prior_year':2018
}

doc.render(context) #it seems here's is the problem, I'not sure
doc.save('output1.docx')
```

And my template looks like this:

[image]

However, when I tried to render the document I got this message:

**expected token 'end of print statement', got 'r'**

I'm new at this, so please can you help me?

Comment: `py r` should be `py_r`

Comment: In the table, at box Raw Materials, December 31 (top left box), is that `py r`? With a space? I believe this is the problem.

Comment: in which part of the code?

Comment: Oh, I could not find it before. I was looking for a blank space and you did it. Thank you! By the way, someone could tell me where I can learn how to get automated reports in docx files where the data is obtained from excel documents?